# tar command use difference

Tags: linux, tar

I know tar -j is for bzip2 file, tar -z is for gzip. However I can't remember which one is for which one. Everytime I would look it up. Is there any good way to remember it or can someone tell me why is this

Comment: So how did you figure out which one was which for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bzip2` was written by **J**ulian Seward.

`gzip` originated with Stallman's **G**NU. Some standard UNIX commands where altered (improved IMHO), and perhaps to highlight the difference, `g` was added as a prefix. Hence `gawk`, `gcc`, etc. as alternatives to `awk`, `cc`, etc.

So, remember: `-j` for Julian's bzip2, and `-z` for [g]zip.

(I don't know if the `-j` option was *chosen* because of Julian's name or if that's simply a happy coincidence.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use either either. Instead tar the file first and then use bzip or gzip to compress in a separate pipe.

```
tar cf - A | gzip -9 > B.tar.gz
```

Same goes for bzip2